# React Admin, second input filter based on first value

Tags: reactjs, state, react-admin

It's my first time there so I hope I'll be clear !

I'm using React-admin for a project and I've got a strange issue. I'm using a modal and in there, there are two fields, one to select a warehouse (for my project) and the second that is parsing location based on the warehouse selected. The problem is that when I select a location once the warehouse is chosen, a second query is called without filter (but just after choosing a warehouse there is the good query).

Example: I choose "WHBOB", the query is filtering WHBOB, and when I click to the location, a second query is passing without filter. I think, the state that I'm using is resetting the filter but I don't know how to fix it ...

Code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import { AutocompleteInput, ReferenceInput, SelectInput } from 'react-admin'
import { Box, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import ProductReceptionInputs from 'components/ProductReceptionInputs'

const useSmallBodyStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: theme.palette.secondary.contrastText
  }
})
)

const ProductLogisticInputs = (props) => {
  const classes = useSmallBodyStyles()

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState()

  function handleChange (evt) {
    setSelectedOption(evt.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant='body2' color='secondary.contrastText' className={classes.root}>Atelier</Typography>

      <Box display='flex' width='100%'>
        <Box width='320px'>
          <SelectInput
            label='Atelier' source='warehouse'
            choices={[
              { id: 'WHBOB', name: 'Bobigny' },
              { id: 'WHLIL', name: 'Lille' },
              { id: 'WHLYO', name: 'Lyon' }
            ]} alwaysOn emptyText='Atelier' fullWidth
            InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Box>

        <Box width='320px' marginLeft='24px'>

          <ReferenceInput
            label='Emplacement'
            reference='location'
            source='location'
            filter={{ ancestor_path: selectedOption }}
            alwaysOn
          >
            <AutocompleteInput
              optionValue='id'
              optionText='name'
              options={{ disabled: !selectedOption }}
              fullWidth
            />
          </ReferenceInput>
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <Typography variant='body2' color='secondary.contrastText' className={classes.root}>Reception</Typography>
      <ProductReceptionInputs />
    </>
  )
}

export default ProductLogisticInputs
```

If you need more info do not hesitate to ask !

Hope I was clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that case (linking 2 options) you should use `FormDataConsumer`. Here is the documentation: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs